# Selection sorting java array

Tags: java, selection-sort

I'm doing a project in which I must generate an array list the size of a user input(in this case i chose 4), with random numbers between -1000 and 1000. Then I have to have it do a selection sort and display both the unsorted numbers in output1 and the sorted numbers in output2 Heres what I have thus far

```
ArrayList <Integer> unSortedNumbers = new ArrayList <Integer>();
Integer [] numberSort;
```

...

```
private void SortActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String input, sortedNumberOutput = "";
    int int1, int2 = 0, min = -1000, max = 1000, j, minimum, temp = 0;
    input = Input.getText();
    int1 = Integer.parseInt(input);

    Random number = new Random();

    while (int2 < int1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < int1; i++) {
            int randomInt = number.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            unSortedNumbers.add(randomInt);
            int1--;
        }
    }

    numberSort = new Integer[unSortedNumbers.size()];
    unSortedNumbers.toArray(numberSort);


    for (int i = 0; i < numberSort.length; i++) {
        sortedNumberOutput += numberSort[i] + (i != numberSort.length ? "," : "");

    }
    if (Selection.isSelected() && Ascending.isSelected()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberSort.length - 1; i++) {
            minimum = numberSort[i];
            for (j = i + 1; j <= numberSort.length - 1; j++) {
                if (minimum > numberSort[j]) {
                    numberSort[temp] = numberSort[i];
                    numberSort[i] = numberSort[j];
                    numberSort[j] = numberSort[temp];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Output1.setText("Unsorted Numbers " + unSortedNumbers);
    Output2.setText("Sorted Numbers " + numberSort);
    unSortedNumbers.clear();
    numberSort = null;
}
```

So when I run that, the unSortedNumbers are displayed properly in output1, but instead of displaying the sorted numbers in output2, it displays this : 
Sorted Numbers [Ljava.lang.Integer;@7a279c

I'm not sure why this is happening, my could is probably wrong somewhere, If you can help, thank you!

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString` to display the content of an array.

Comment: hmm, that didn't work but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: `Output2.setText("Sorted Numbers " + Arrays.toString(numberSort));` should work.

Comment: Okay, sorry, i had something different.

Okay i changed it and it works, seems theres something wrong with my sort though, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the result of the default toString() method being called on an array object.  [Ljava.lang.Integer tells you it is an array of Integers and the @7a279c gives you the hex string of the hashcode.  Do as ZouZou suggests and use `Arrays.toString(unSortedNumbers);`